# How to change an attribute of a nested SVG element without an ID?

Tags: svg, height, rect

I want to change the height of `rect`

```
<clipPath xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svge-1">
    <rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="761" height="231" />
</clipPath>
```

According to this, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/scripting.html#changing-attribute-values, it should be easy but the problem is the `rect` here does not have an `id`.

How can I add an `id` to it or access the `height` of `rect` here?

Answer (score 1):

There are several other ways to retrieve the element using DOM.

You can use `getElementById('svge-1')` to get the parent element, and get the elements named `rect` using `getElementsByTagName` in the context of that element. This will give you the first (and only) `rect` element:

```
var clipPathElement = document.getElementById("svge-1");
var rectElement = clipPathElement.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0];
```

You could also use DOM attributes to get the child *elements* ignoring their name with `children`. This will give you the first element, which is `rect`:

```
var rectElement = clipPathElement.children[0];
```

You could also use `childNodes`, but you would have to get the second object(`childNodes[1]`), since it contains *all* nodes (not only elements) which includes the whitespace text node before the tag.

From there you can change any attribute you want:

```
rectElement.setAttribute("height", "100");
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/5x9Qn/)** with a working example.